# Which has more Offline Single Player Content: Call of Duty Infinite Warfare or Titanfall 2?

Tags: titanfall-2, call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

I showed my dad a magazine of games for him to pick out a game to get for Christmas. despite being told that he's getting only one he picked two: *Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare* and *Titanfall 2*.

When I got him his Christmas present last year we wanted to choose between *Assassin's Creed Syndicate*, *Halo 5* and *Fallout 4* but I chose *Fallout 4* because I knew it'll last him much longer than the other two. I want to do the same this year but I'm unsure which has more offline Single Player Content.

So which game has more Offline Single Player Content? *Call of Duty Infinite Warfare* or *Titanfall 2*?

By Offline Single Player Content I'm talking about gameplay which is single player and doesn't require the internet. How long would it take on average to complete everything for single player in one difficulty (preferably the easiest since my dad starts off with that).

Comment: Subjective, but Titanfall 2's single player campaign was more enjoyable than a lot of recent CoD campaigns. (I haven't played Infinite Warfare, but Advanced Warfare/Ghosts).

Answer (score 7):

Using one of my favorite sites for gaming How Long to Beat here is a chart on how long it would take you to beat Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare's single player.

```
PlayStyle   Polled  Average Median  Rushed  Leisure
Main Story      24  6h 53m  7h      5h 58m  8h 08m
Main + Extras   24  8h 20m  7h 59m  7h      9h 57m
Completionists  4   9h 43m  9h 15m  8h 14m  11h 27m
All PlayStyles  52  7h 46m  7h 34m  6h 20m  10h 32m
```

So for CoD:IW if you play at an average pace, you should be able to get around 8 hours of gameplay out of purely the single player.

Using the same site for Titanfall 2's single player:

```
PlayStyle   Polled  Average Median  Rushed  Leisure
Main Story      75  5h 37m  5h 30m  4h 23m  7h 26m
Main + Extras   15  7h 40m  7h      6h  10m 10h 25m
Completionists  5   12h 25m 12h     11h 17m 13h 56m
All PlayStyles  95  6h 18m  6h      4h  41m 10h 54m
```

Which states you would get around 6 hours of gameplay out of the single player of Titanfall 2. So if you are going purely for single player Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare has higher average times to beat in all categories so that would be your best bet for single player only content.

Sources: https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=38000

https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=37101

Comment: I'm curious, what are the "extras" for Titanfall?

Comment: Usually the extras on How long to beat refer to things like post game content and other side activities. Pretty much kind of like the middle ground between just completing the main story, and the completionist tiers.

Answer (score 3):

I would say Infinite Warfare is the better choice because the campaign ranges from 5-7 hours on the easiest difficulty (definitely longer on harder difficulties) [from one post I've read](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189938-call-of-duty-infinite-warfare/74519524) and you also can play the zombies mode offline ([on consoles only](https://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Call-of-Duty-Infinite-Warfare-Zombies-FAQ)) which is fantastic if I must say. You can't put a definite number on how long the zombies mode can take since there is no real objective, unless you consider the Easter egg the end goal in which case, it can easily take hours and multiple games. From what I read and hear, the campaign is one of the better Call of Duty campaigns made. I unfortunately haven't played the campaign yet, but I'm positive it will take me longer than 5-7 hours (I play on veteran).

Titanfall 2's campaign from what I read [is about 8 hours](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2016/08/12/titanfall-2-single-player-campaign-length-revealed/). This is longer than the first games campaign of "0" (said in quotes because the first game had a multiplayer "campaign" which was basically the multiplayer game modes with some back story added in.  You didn't even play on different maps).  As far as I know, that's all the offline content for the game. Not too surprising when it's predecessor was online only.

**Edit:** Since posting, I started the campaign for Infinite Warfare on veteran and only managed to beat 3 levels in about 2.5 hours. I would say on the easiest difficulty you can cut that time in half.